# Parse String to Integer in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, type-conversion, masm

I've code that should parse String format to int but it changes f.e. 0 to 658688 and I don't know what to do with it.
Is the lodsd command correct here?

```
toparse DB 128 dup(?)
mov toparse, "0"

  atoi proc uses esi edx inputBuff:DWORD
mov esi, inputBuff
xor edx, edx
.Repeat
lodsd
.Break .if !eax
imul edx, edx, 10
sub eax, "0"
add edx, eax
.Until 0
mov EAX, EDX
ret
  atoi endp
```

it returns 658688

Comment: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_160.html  ... `lodsd` may be correct, if your string encoding is UTF-32 or other 4 byte encoding. It probably is not, as do `mov toparse, "0"`. Did you check in debugger, what is happening? It's difficult to read your source, as it's not pure assembly, I think there are some macros or something... or are those "todo" comments maybe.

Comment: @ped These are not comments. The code uses MASM's high-level assembly syntax. I guess they are like macros, but they're built into the assembler.

Comment: `lodsd` is wrong. It loads a double-word (DWORD), but your characters are obviously byte-sized, since you've declared a string array using `DB` (Declare Byte). You probably want `lodsb`.

Comment: Your result value 658688 in hex is `0x0A0D00`, so the good news is your code works (the low byte is `0`, as intended). I bet the other two bytes came from your input routine: the Enter that you ended it with. So if you are going to adjust for a loop, either test for the of end your input string, or check each character to see it's a digit, in this routine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either `invoke` the atoi proc with the ascii's memory offset or `push` the offset before `call`ing atoi. Right now `esi` will just contain the random values that are already in `inputbuff`.

I have revised the proc so that it will process full strings successfully.

```
toparse db "12345678",0

;mov toparse,"0" ; Max is 4 bytes so define string above

push offset toparse ; |
call atoi           ; - or: invoke atoi,offset toparse  

...

atoi proc uses esi inputBuff:DWORD ; Generally only need to preserve esi, edi and ebx
mov esi,inputBuff
xor edx,edx
xor eax,eax         ; Clear register
.Repeat
lodsb               ; Get one byte
.Break .if !eax
imul edx,edx,10     ; Multiply total by 10
sub eax,"0"         ; Subtract 48
add edx,eax         ; Add result to the total
.Until 0
mov eax,edx         ; Will result in 00BC614E (hex 12345678)
ret
atoi endp
```

Comment: [`lodsd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LODS:LODSB:LODSW:LODSD:LODSQ.html) loads 4 bytes and increments ESI by 4.  Unless your characters are stored as UTF-32, that's not going to work.  You should either zero EAX ahead of the loop and use LODSB, or use `movzx eax, byte [esi]` / `inc esi` (which is only 2 uops instead of 3 for LODSB on recent Intel CPUs).

Comment: Also, your code still falls into `atoi` after the `call` returns.  But good point about having to use a `call` to put args where MASM's macro-like stuff loads it from for `mov esi, inputBuff`.  IMO that just makes it harder to see what's really happening vs. `mov esi, [ebp+8]` (or `[esp+4]` if you didn't make a stack frame).

Comment: So you're saying your code works, but only for a single-digit number?  And LODSD zeroes the rest of EAX by loading zeros from the next three bytes, including 2 bytes past the end of the buffer?  That will break as soon as you include this code in a program that has anything else in its data section, since then you can't count on the bytes after the buffer being zero.

Comment: That's a much more useful answer for the OP and for all future readers (which is the real point of SO).  +1

Comment: These string-to-integer questions usually have a bunch of other bugs, so they don't make good targets for closing other questions as duplicates.  This one actually does work well as a canonical string-to-integer question, and isn't full of 16-bit DOS I/O code or anything.